# Pass variable from html to Javascript on button click Format If statment

Tags: javascript, html

Iam trying to have button's on a html page and format my output with an if statement in javascript But I cant get it to work, I either get both(cant be correct) or (neither) Ive formatted the code here as an example, it does not work but hopefully you will be able to understand and answer my query.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function handleIt(n){
    if (n = "A"){alert("A");}
    if (n = "D"){alert("D");}
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Admin Control panel :</h1>
   <button type="button"id="A"onclick="handleIt(n)">+</button>
   <button type="button"id="D"onclick="handleIt("D")">-</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues,

```
if (n = "A"){ } 
//as Will pointed out
//this statement represents assignment which is always TRUE
//but in your case, it's equality(i hope) which can be TRUE or FALSE depended on your both variables
```

And

```
<button type="button"id="D"onclick="handleIt("D")">-</button> 
<!--onclick is written incorrect, use single quotes instead, "handleIt('D')"-->
```

Below is working sample

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function handleIt(n){
    if (n == "A"){ alert("A"); }
    if (n == "D"){ alert("D"); }
  }
</script>
<button type="button" id="A" onclick="handleIt('A')">+</button>
<button type="button" id="D" onclick="handleIt('D')">-</button>
```

Comment: Pretty sure every person with an account on Stack Overflow did the `if(n = 'A'){ }` thing in some language at some point. :) To be clear, that's assigning `n` the value `A` instead of checking to see if `n` is equal to "A". Thing is, *it is a valid statement* (just not what the OP wanted) and that's the problem! Since you can assign a variable there it gets returned as `TRUE` each time. https://jsfiddle.net/vxL4vam0/

Comment: @Will Great point Will, that's exactly what i would add to answer

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the code is not correct,
"=" sign inside if condition is used to assign the value, and not compare it.
To compare you can use either "==" or "==="
Also there is a syntax error related to the quotes in

```
 <button type="button"id="D"onclick="handleIt("D")">-</button>
```

Here is what updated code would look like:

```
<h1>Admin Control panel :</h1>
   <button type="button"id="A" onclick="handleIt('A')">+</button>
   <button type="button"id="D" onclick="handleIt('D')">-</button>

   <script>
   function handleIt(n){
    if (n == "A"){alert("A");}
    if (n == "D"){alert("D");}
  }
   </script>
```

Here is the fiddle for the same:
https://jsfiddle.net/g5st4c5m/1/